# Javascript timeout in CXP project

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

How do I write a script to redirect to main menu after no user input i.e. touch, mouse, keyboard for 30 seconds? On Voxeo(Aspect) CXP you do get a dialog timeout, which is set by default to 5min, but that's on each and every dialog. I would just like to logout automatically if there's no user input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a build in feature called *Auto-advance*: 
http://help.voxeo.com/go/cxp14/objectreference.output.definition.options

This will go to your the next object in your flow after some time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While providing a link may be helpful, it is recommended to insert main parts into your answer, so please do it (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Best regards.